# What parameter to use to decide if accelerometer data are noisy?

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, snr, regression

I would like to do regression thus I need to know if my input data are noisy.

In this case, I generate accelerometer data `[x, y, z]` from the sensor.

I have a look at RMS noise, SNR etc, but I couldn't understand, which one to use to decide if data are noisy. Let's say I have some RMS noise values, but when exactly do we accept that the data are noisy and thus implement filters?

Comment: You need to _edit your question_.  Do you have a data sheet?  Can you take measurements with your accelerometer not moving, or moving in some very predictable way?

Comment: I just have the measurements, the dataset is available here: [link](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hkayan/industrial-robotic-arm-anomaly-detection).

Comment: If you don't know how the accelerometer is moving, you cannot distinguish noise from real motion.  So unless you _do_ know and you're not telling us, that's pretty much the end of the story -- you don't have enough information.

Comment: Alright, many thanks Tim.